# Disable access to Azure Devops for already uninstalled extension

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

Last week we installed an extension to backup our Azure DevOps organisation (Backrightup Backup). After a few tests we decided to cancel this extension and we uninstalled the extension.

Still, everyday a backup is made in one of our storage accounts.

How do I kill all access to our Azure Devops environment so that backups are no longer created? How do I even manage the permissions of extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Backrightup extension permission is based on the your account which is the project collection administrator role.

After investigation, you need to remove the account from DevOps organization(if you're owner, change owner to another account), and then add your account back to the organization(change owner back if needed).

In addition, please also remove below permissions:

1. Go to `https://aex.dev.azure.com/me` with your account, make sure the  AAD domain is correct under your account. -> Manage Authorizations -> **Revoke** the app Backrightup.com.
   [image]
2. Delete the enterprise app Backrightup on azure portal.
   [image]
3. Uninstall Backrightup extension on DevOps organization.
4. Go to project, **remove** webhook to BackrightUp.

[image]

Comment: I already did 2 and 3, will try the rest later.

Comment: After 1,2,3,4 done, please do member to remove your account and add it back. Do not authorize to  Backrightup website again as it quires permission during login process.

Comment: Okay, step one did remove the permissions, as I thought the red button would do. Why should I remove my account? the permissions do no longer show.
And do i seriously need to delete all webhooks from all projects one by one? Jeez....what a pain.

Comment: When i checked on my side, i revoked the app Backrightup.com(step1), on the `already-opened`  Backrightup.com website, it still can restore and backup repos, so i deleted and add the account back to make sure the permission is removed. For the webhook to backrightup, you can check if they exists(not all projects have on my side), delete them as it could be triggered when event meets, to avoid work item backup.

Comment: Thanks, I cleaned everything with your great description. There is no trace anymore of Backrightup on our DevOps site. What a relief! I am so happy right now.

Comment: Glad to know it helps! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found it. In Microsoft Entra ID, I went to 'Enterprise applications' and  sorted the applications by date.

The first entry was of the Azure DevOps Extension. I deleted this entry (by selecting it, going to properties and delete).

I hope tomorrow no new backups are created. I will update this answer when I have results.

Edited: Nope, although i think it is good i got rid of this entry, it was not enough.

But today I found another entry in my DevOps environment:
[image]

I will delete this and post any results.

Frustrating. This row cannot be deleted. Clicking the red button does nothing.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your sharing! May i know if it's resolved? If it is, it's recommended you to [accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so that it could help others who have some query with you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Wade, Thanks for reaching out. The issue is not resolved yet. See my edit in the answer above.

Comment: Besides above change, you can check the mailbox, find the email with title `New app(s) connected to your Microsoft account`, click 'manage app' button , or you can directly access page `https://account.live.com/consent/Manage?`, Edit for Backrightup, remove all permission for a check.

Comment: Why should this be done in live.com? I do not use a Personal Microsoft account, but a work MS account.

Comment: I tested with Microsoft account. If you are using work account, please also check the email box. When you register the backrightup.com, it will create the app to your account profile. You can find the email, click the manage app button, to remove the  Backrightup permission.

Comment: I have no e-mail in my mailbox containing the words "New app(s) connected". I also checked all mail i received on the day I registered with backrightup.com: Nothing. But above all, I think the red button should work, regardless of the e-mail.